# Algorithm to find pairs depending on m

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to write an algorithm to find the number of pairs based on m.

m is equal to the number of times a[i] appears in an array (e.g. if the number 3 appears two times then m=2).

If m<2 then there are no pairs, if m=2 then 1 pair, if m=3 then 3 pairs, if m=4 then 6 pairs, and so on.

Comment: Sorry but it is very unclear to me what the problem is. Could you try to rephrase it?

Comment: would be great if you could give some examples

Comment: I rephrased it now. Hopefully, it's easier to understand.

Comment: @Henry Thank you! That is working perfectly.

Comment: Please demonstrate your personal effort to solve a problem in the question's body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is still not very clear, but the number of pairs that can be built out of m items is (m choose 2) = m*(m-1)/2.